# Cannot connect to concourse's slack inviter

Tags: concourse

I tried clicking on the "Slack inviter" - see here: https://concourse-ci.org/community.html

"404 Not Found: Requested route ('slack.concourse.ci') does not exist."

Is this a temporary problem?

Answer (score 1):

This was a temporary problem with our website and should now be fixed. Sorry for the inconvenience!

You can access our Slack inviter either through the [community](https://concourse.ci/community.html) page that you linked to or through this [direct link](http://slack.concourse.ci/) to the inviter itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary problem. The slack inviter should be up again soon.

Answer (score 0):

Concourse's Slack channel has now been retired, and replaced with a [Discourse forum system](https://discuss.concourse-ci.org/) for users and a Discord chat system for Concourse developers.